How can I ensure that a Rust closure implements the `FnMut` trait?
I'm writing a simple Rust program that streams sufficiently loud audio input to an output device.
I got the input and output callbacks to share state by using ringbuf in a manner heavily inspired by this code.
However, when I tried to use a mutable reference of one of my structs in the function, I encountered error E0525:
error[E0525]: expected a closure that implements the `FnMut` trait, but this closure only implements `FnOnce`
   --> src/main.rs:59:25
    |
59  | ...et input_data_fn = move |data: &[f32], _: &cpal::InputCallbackInfo| {
    |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ this closure implements `FnOnce`, not `FnMut`
60  | ...   let mut output_fell_behind = false;
61  | ...   massager.ingest(data.to_vec());
    |       -------- closure is `FnOnce` because it moves the variable `massager` out of its environment
...
84  | ...et input_stream = input.build_input_stream(&config, input_data_fn, err_f...
    |                            ------------------          ------------- the requirement to implement `FnMut` derives from here
    |                            |
    |                            required by a bound introduced by this call
    |
note: required by a bound in `build_input_stream`
   --> C:\Users\info\.cargo\registry\src\index.crates.io-6f17d22bba15001f\cpal-0.15.3\src\traits.rs:134:12
    |
125 |     fn build_input_stream<T, D, E>(
    |        ------------------ required by a bound in this associated function
...
134 |         D: FnMut(&[T], &InputCallbackInfo) + Send + 'static,
    |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `DeviceTrait::build_input_stream`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0525`.

Here is a simplified minimal example of code that produces this error (and the full source code if anyone is interested):
Note: Apologies for the long example, but build_input_stream is necessary because it requires that the closure implements the  FnMut trait.
use cpal::traits::{DeviceTrait, HostTrait, StreamTrait};
use ringbuf::{
    traits::{Producer, Split},
    HeapRb,
};

fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    // Setting up audio devices, ignore this code
    let host = cpal::default_host();

    let input = host
        .default_input_device()
        .expect("No input device available");
    println!(
        "Using output device {}",
        input.name().unwrap_or("unnamed".to_owned())
    );
    let input_config = input
        .default_input_config()
        .expect("No default input config");
    let input_sample_format = input_config.sample_format();
    let input_sample_rate = input_config.sample_rate().0 as f32;
    let input_channels = input_config.channels() as usize;

    let output = host
        .default_output_device()
        .expect("No output device available");
    println!(
        "Using output device {}",
        output.name().unwrap_or("unnamed".to_owned())
    );
    let output_config = output
        .default_output_config()
        .expect("No default output config");
    let output_sample_format = output_config.sample_format();
    let output_sample_rate = output_config.sample_rate().0 as f32;
    let output_channels = output_config.channels() as usize;

    let config: cpal::StreamConfig = output_config.into();
    let latency_frames = 1.0 * config.sample_rate.0 as f32;
    let latency_samples = latency_frames as usize * output_channels as usize;

    let ring = HeapRb::<f32>::new(latency_samples * 2);

    // MUTABLE VARIABLES FROM A 3RD PARTY LIBRARY:
    let (mut producer, mut consumer) = ring.split();
    for _ in 0..latency_samples {
        producer.try_push(0.0).unwrap();
    }
    
    // MY MUTABLE VARIABLES:
    let mut massager = DataMassager::new();

    let input_data_fn = move |data: &[f32], _: &cpal::InputCallbackInfo| {
        let mut output_fell_behind = false;
        // THE CALL THAT IS CAUSING PROBLEMS
        massager.ingest(data.to_vec());

        match massager.next() {
            Some(samples) => {
                for sample in samples {
                    if producer.try_push(sample).is_err() {
                        output_fell_behind = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            None => {
                for i in 0..data.len() {
                    if producer.try_push(0.0).is_err() {
                        output_fell_behind = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        if output_fell_behind {
            eprintln!("output stream fell behind: try increasing latency");
        }
    };

    let input_stream = input.build_input_stream(&config, input_data_fn, err_fn, None)?;
    input_stream.play()?;

    Ok(())
}

fn err_fn(err: cpal::StreamError) {
    eprintln!("an error occurred on stream: {}", err);
}

// A useless iterator to illustrate this bug
pub struct DataMassager {
    buffer: Vec<Vec<f32>>,
}

impl DataMassager {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let buffer: Vec<Vec<f32>> = vec![];
        return DataMassager { buffer };
    }

    pub fn ingest(mut self, chunk: Vec<f32>) {
        self.buffer.insert(0, chunk);
    }
}

impl Iterator for DataMassager {
    type Item = Vec<f32>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        return self.buffer.pop();
    }
}


Please create a Minimal Reproducible Example.

Fair enough @ChayimFriedman, I'll put something together

I've been trying to trim the example but I'm getting a much more straightforward error message: borrow of moved value. I'm afraid the example may have to be quite large.

I was wondering why the mutable function try_push didn't result in the same error as my ingest function. It turns out that the answer is in the signature:
    fn try_push(&mut self, elem: Self::Item) -> Result<(), Self::Item> {

It uses &mut -- a mutable reference.
The reason my code would not compile is that I was using mut without any reference, denoting a move rather than a borrow.
    pub fn ingest(mut self, chunk: Chunk) {

The solution is adding one character
    pub fn ingest(&mut self, chunk: Chunk) {


If it wasn't for the constraints on build_input_stream, this code would have resulted in a much more straightforward borrow of moved value error. As far as I can tell this is the underlying error.

It's kind of a special case of "borrow of moved value." It's similar in some ways to when you move a value in a loop, and then the loop has a chance to continue. You'll get an error because the next iteration of the loop might use the moved value. In this case, what it's saying is that a closure you're using as an FnMut or Fn moves one of its captured values, but doesn't replace the value. The result is that if the function gets called again, it will use a value that has been moved. This is why the closure only implements FnOnce -- you can only call it once.

This is why it doesn't just say "borrow of moved value" -- that doesn't actually happen. Because the closure moves out of one of its captured values, it just doesn't implement Fn or FnMut. It only implements FnOnce because it's only safe to call it once. When you understand this, the error message from the compiler makes total sense.
